# How to print a line based on user input and randomly selected choices

Tags: java, output, user-input

I'm working on a code for my first ever java class.  Its rock paper scissors (lizard spock).  The program runs perfectly for allowing input and outputting a random choice by the computer.  However, I'd like the program to say something like "its at tie" or "you win" when the situation is right.  So far, I haven't been able to get this.  I had it say "its a tie" to the wrong situation once, and only once without being able to replicate it.  My code is:

import java.util.*;

class rock {
    public static void main( String args[ ] ) {

```
    System.out.println( "rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spock?" );
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner ( System.in );
    String guess;
    guess = user_input.next( );

    String [ ] comp;
        comp = new String [ 5 ];
        comp[ 0 ] = "Rock";
        comp[ 1 ] = "Paper";
        comp[ 2 ] = "Scissors";
        comp[ 3 ] = "Lizard";
        comp[ 4 ] = "Spock";

        Random hi;
        hi = new Random( );
        System.out.println( "::" + guess +
            ":: vs ::" + comp[ hi.nextInt( 5 ) ] + "::") ;

            if (guess.equals( "rock" ) & comp[ hi.nextInt( 5 ) ].equals(1) ) System.out.println( "Its a tie" );

}
```

}

I only have one output right now, but once I understand what to do I will add one for each situation.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: p.s. I know rock vs paper isn't a tie, I was just trying different things. Plz don't judge me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple details that might help you there:

You need to use && instead of & to test a logical AND

The convention is that a class name starts with a Caps: Rock

You are calling nextInt() twice, it will potentially return two different values. If you want the same, you should call it once and store it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was a bit confused before I read this as I was getting nonsensical errors but calling nextInt() twice was the issue

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a check on each scenario using if else statements.
Just be cautious not to make any redundant checks.

Example:

```
String compChoice = comp[hi.nextInt(5)];
if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase( compChoice )) { 
System.out.println("its a tie!");
}
else if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase( "rock" ) && compChoice.equals("paper")){
System.out.println("You lose");
}
```

and so on.

Also I advise you change your:

```
if (guess.equals( "rock" )
```

To:

```
If (guess.equalsIgnoreCase( "rock" )
```

This is just so if the user does enter anything like "roCK" the capitalization doesn't mess anything up.

Comment: I used your suggestions and after getting my parentheses in the right places (I had 100 errors due to them being misplaced!) it works perfectly. Thank you